# Get the written version of any number in JavaScript or JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I have is the following:

```
var numbers = new Array("one", "two", "three", ...);
```

Using this I can get the text version of any number I'd like (by using `numbers[index + 1]`).  The thing is, what if I wanted 23,456,789 converted to text, or even 22?  I'd have to spend the rest of my life adding to this array to account for any numbers added.

Is there a standard JS or JQuery function available that'll give me the text-representation of any number?  Ideally I'd like them with no spaces and no symbols (i.e. 22=twentytwo, 120=onehundredtwenty).

The application is for **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/gGB4x/8/)** fiddle example.  Detailed explanation of said fiddle can be found at **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978551/ordering-a-graphical-list-via-mouse-dragging-using-javascript/22122131#22122131)** other thread of mine.

Currently, this issue is the biggest hurdle for truly having a use-anywhere code.

I could use something like:

```
function numbers(a){
    var ones = new Array("one", "two", "three", ...);
    var tens = new Array("", "twenty", "thirty", ...);
}
```

And then split apart the number and apply the appropriate text.  But is there a simpler, existing method?  Before I go through with writing the function.

**EDIT:**

I was hoping for a simple one-liner.  In the end all I need are unique classes, based off of their numerical position in a list, so I've got something like...

```
function toNumber(a) {
    var numbers = new Array("zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine");

    var sNumber = a.toString();

    for (var i = 0, len = sNumber.length; i < len; i += 1) {
        $('p').append(numbers[sNumber[i]]);
    }
}
```

Does it well enough.

Comment: No love for `"zero"`, ey?

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=javascript+convert+numbers+to+words&oq=convert+javascript+numbers+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.8528j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

```
var th = ['','thousand','million', 'billion','trillion'];
var dg = ['zero','one','two','three','four', 'five','six','seven','eight','nine']; 
var tn = ['ten','eleven','twelve','thirteen', 'fourteen','fifteen','sixteen', 'seventeen','eighteen','nineteen'];
var tw = ['twenty','thirty','forty','fifty', 'sixty','seventy','eighty','ninety']; 

function toWords(s)
    {  
        s = s.toString(); 
        s = s.replace(/[\, ]/g,''); 
        if (s != parseFloat(s)) return 'not a number'; 
        var x = s.indexOf('.'); 
        if (x == -1) x = s.length; 
        if (x > 15) return 'too big'; 
        var n = s.split(''); 
        var str = ''; 
        var sk = 0; 
        for (var i=0; i < x; i++) 
        {
            if ((x-i)%3==2) 
            {
                if (n[i] == '1') 
                {
                    str += tn[Number(n[i+1])] + ' '; 
                    i++; 
                    sk=1;
                }
                else if (n[i]!=0) 
                {
                    str += tw[n[i]-2] + ' ';
                    sk=1;
                }
            }
            else if (n[i]!=0) 
            {
                str += dg[n[i]] +' '; 
                if ((x-i)%3==0) str += 'hundred ';
                sk=1;
            }

            if ((x-i)%3==1)
            {
                if (sk) str += th[(x-i-1)/3] + ' ';
                sk=0;
            }
        }
        if (x != s.length)
        {
            var y = s.length; 
            str += 'point '; 
            for (var i=x+1; i<y; i++) str += dg[n[i]] +' ';
        }
        return str.replace(/\s+/g,' ');
    }
```

Comment: from source http://ravindersinghdang.blogspot.com/2013/04/convert-numbers-into-words-using.html    this was first result in google for your question, discover the power of a search engine :-)